# C++ - Can't print target of a char pointer

Tags: c++

I have a method in C++ that receives a `char * data` as a parameter, like this:

`bool Whatever::method(char * data) { ... }`

Now, I want to print the contents of that array. If I try:

```
for (int i = 0...) {
    cout << *(data+i) << endl;
}
```

it will only print blank spaces. No garbage, just blanks. But if I cast to `int *` and then dereference, it kind of works (but of course it prints the values as integers):

```
for (int i = 0...) {
    cout << *(int*)(data+i) << endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

***Edit:***

The contents of the array are the following:

- An `enum`
- A `char[6]`
- A `long`

What I get is a blank space per `char`. Even if I remove the `for` loop and try something like `cout << *data << endl;` (which should print the first character) it will still print a blank.

I understand that the `long` won't be correctly printed if I interpret it as a `char`, and the `enum` is just a number after all, but anyway I should be able to interpret them as characters... Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:c] tag for C++ questions. They are different languages.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::cout << data`?

Comment: Can you include the contents of the `data` array in your post, and also what your program prints? It's important that we see the difference between what you want and what you get.

Comment: @remyabel: `std::cout << data` will only work if `data` is null-terminated. Since the code is looping through `data`, and thus has a stop condition, that suggests to me that `data` is probably not null terminated, but that is just a guess.

Comment: [I don't see any problem in this](http://ideone.com/BNVZzi)

Comment: By the way, the *content* of a pointer is the value in the pointer, i.e. the address that it points to.  Printing of a pointer's value or content is different than printing the object it points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
*(int*)(data+i)
```

casts the `char*` pointer formed by `data+i` to `int*`, and dereferences. This would access `sizeof(int)` `char`-values as an `int`, except that it's Undefined Behavior so it might really do anything. In particular at the end of the array.

If you're interested in outputting the numerical values, instead do

```
+data[i]
```

which promotes the `char` value to `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually not interested in printing the numerical values, but the characters that form the array of chars. I've tried different methods but none works.

Comment: @Ypsilon: when you output the numerical values, what are they?

Comment: Something like this:
0
33554432
131072
512
2
0
0 (one per line)

Comment: @Ypsilon: Well that's your problem right at the start, a zero byte, which says that this is a C string of length 0. Following that you have some data that's probably garbage from whatever this memory area was used for earlier. As ASCII it's “!7,” followed by a Windows newline, that is, carriage return plus linefeed. After that, just meaningless garbage starting with “H3”.